# NullPointerException when using advanced admob

Tags: nullpointerexception, admob, native

After i change the admob lib from 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0' to 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.0', There is an exception happens

The crash log is :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'android.view.View xq.e()' on a null object reference
>       at rx.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:686)
>       at rr.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:3308)
>       at rr.onGlobalLayout(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:561)
>       at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout(ViewTreeObserver.java:986)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2210)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1301)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7016)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

And i report a [bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/jXQW4gwUEDs) in google group:

I am not sure what should i do to resolve this issue.

BR

Keven

Comment: Use AdSense, maybe? It's harder to get approved, but much better for you and the users. Coming back to your question, do you use GMS in your app?

Comment: Yes, i using the lib: 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.1' to to show the admob.